# deploy django to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to deploy my django project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. My project was not create through eb-virt. Do I need to redo the project again in eb-virt? I have no idea of how to deploy my project directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always recommended to work on a virtual environment. it is important because you can have your very own python environment with all the modules you need for the app installed. The good news is that it's not yet late to create the virtual environment.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

## to setup the project

1. goto your folder
2. create the virtual environment using `virtualenv ~/eb-virt`
3. activate the virtual environment `source ~/eb-virt/bin/activate`
4. install django `pip install django==2.1.1`
5. create the requirements.txt file by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. because elasticbeanstalk can install the dependecies mentioned in this file.
6. do the 3rd to 5th steps from the link above

## to deploy

follow the deploy section, basically

1. init the project `eb init -p python-3.6 django-tutorial`
2. create an environment `eb create django-env`, we used to have Dev, staging and production environments
3. continue steps 4th to 7th